# Replace colors in PDF using ghostscript

Tags: pdf, colors, pdf-generation, ghostscript

How can I convert a single color from a PDF document into another color, for example convert all instances of #ff0000 (red) to #ffffff (white)?

I've seen a number of ghostscript commands doing something similar (using setcolor, setcolortransfer), but I can't find a solution for this exact problem.

For example, the follwing will create an image-negative of the input PDF:

```
gs -o output.pdf -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -c "{1 exch sub}{1 exch sub}{1 exch sub}{1 exch sub} setcolortransfer" -f input.pdf
```

I'd move past this with a higher level of control, focusing on a single color being replaced with a different (not it's negative) color.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essentially, you can't (or at least not using Ghostscript).

Firstly you seem to be assuming that the colours will be specified in RGB when in fact they could be specified in CMYK, ICC, CalRGB or Lab. You also need to consider Indexed colour spaces.

Secondly Ghostscript does not 'edit' PDF files, when you send a PDF file as input to Ghostscript it is fully interpreted to graphics primitives and the primitives are processed.

When the output is PDF the primitives are reassembled into a new PDF file. The goal of this process is that the visual appearance of the new PDF file should match the original. It is **NOT** the same PDF file, its internals will likely be completely different.

Finally, how do you plan to handle images ? Will you process those byte by byte to massage the colours ? Or do you plan to ignore them ? Same goes for shadings, where the colours aren't even present in the PDF file directly, but are generated from functions.

Without knowing why you want to do this I can't even offer a different approach other than; decompress the PDF file, read it and replace the colours manually.

Comment: I don't need a high level of replacement precision (shading is not important). I do not know how to detect if the color is CMYK, RGB or something else, I guess I can try a number of combinations and test it out (is there a way to find out which is used in the document?). As for the actual editing, I'm clear that Ghostscript is interpreting the input and generating an output PDF which is just what I want.

Comment: I assume that this PDF I want to process is all images, every page has a two color background I want to "remove" (replace each of the two with white). My guess is that it was possible, based on another post where the colors were inverted (resulting in a image-negative of the original PDF).

Comment: inversion is much easier than specific colour replacement. Handling images is going to be slow, because every image sample needs to be inspected. Your best bet is probably to render the PDFs to an image format, change the colours in an image editor and save them back out as PDF> or use something like MuPDF to extract all the images from the PDF and proceed from there. You could do it with Ghostscript but it would require writing some C code and rebuilding the application.